# Calculating AMP Script Hash With C#

Tags: c#, encoding, hash, amp-html, ampscript

I am trying to calculate the AMP script hash for our site's AMP scripts so we do not have to update them manually each time something in the script changes. We do not use node.js or I would simply use the given solution on the amp-script documentation page (https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-script/). I have tried following the steps for the algorithm listed on the doc page but I haven't been able to get the hash to match the one that is actually needed for the meta link. Here is my code so far...

```
        // Compute sha384 sum of script contents
        var sha384 = SHA384.Create();
        var hashBytes = sha384.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(model.ScriptContents));
        // Express hash sum as hexadecimal
        var hashHex = BitConverter.ToString(hashBytes);
        // Base64url-encode the result
        var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(hashHex)).TrimEnd('=').Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_');
        // Prefix with 'sha384-'
        var hash = "sha384-" + base64;
```

Comment: You're not actually meant to return the `Base64-of-Base16-of-hash`; just the `Base64-of-hash`. I think the part about "This sum should be expressed in hexadecimal." is throwing you off: The page is written for JS devs using `toolbox-script-csp`, and JS libs all have their own special way of handling binary data, whereas in .NET we can use `Byte[]` just fine.

Comment: **IMPORTANT NOTE**: Do not use `String` to represent a JS script file that you'll be hashing _and_ serving: the hash of a String is often different than the original file due to meta information-loss during decoding and re-encoding, even if the script's textual content is identical. For example, non-normalized Unicode bytes being normalized when decoded, missing the leading byte-order-mark (which `Encoding.UTF8` renders by default, btw!) or even line-break conversions from `\n` to `\r\n` (or vice-versa) depending on how your environment is set-up.

Comment: @Dai Thanks for the response! That part about the sum being expressed in hexadecimal is what was confusing to me here... however just doing the Base64-of-hash (the Byte[]) does not give the correct result either.

Comment: Also, you need to dispose of your `sha384` instance (either use a `using()` block, or use the new `static HashData` methods introduced in .NET Core).

Comment: I suggest you try the approach in my answer. The output should be correct as well as matching hashes computed by other programs (e.g. 7Zip's Explorer menu to show hashes). How are you determining if the output is correct or not? If my answer doesn't work then I suspect you're doing something else incorrectly - if so then you'll need to post a lot more context (and code, and sample script files) so we can try to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Ah my mistake, I misread your second comment. I am determining if the output is correct by comparing it to the hash given in the browser's console when the hash is missing or incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually meant to return the `Base64-of-Base16-of-hash`; just the `Base64-of-hash`. I think the part about "This sum should be expressed in hexadecimal." is throwing you off: The instructions on that page are written for JS devs using the `toolbox-script-csp` NPM module, though I agree the person writing it failed to consider non-JS developers.

> Compute the SHA384 hash sum of the script's contents. This sum should be expressed in hexadecimal.

Instead, take a look at the reference implementation in `toolbox-script-csp`:

https://github.com/ampproject/amp-toolbox/blob/main/packages/script-csp/lib/calculateHash.js

```
function calculateHash(src, {algorithm = DEFAULT_ALGORITHM} = {}) {
  const algo = algorithm.toLowerCase();
  if (!SUPPORTED_ALGORITHMS.has(algo)) {
    throw new Error(`Unsupported algorithm for CSP: ${algo}`);
  }

  if (typeof src === 'string') {
    src = Buffer.from(src, 'utf8');
  }

  const hash = crypto.createHash(algo);
  const data = hash.update(src);
  const base64 = base64URLFormat(data.digest('base64'));
  return `${algo}-${base64}`;
}

function base64URLFormat(base64) {
  return base64.replace(/=/g, '').replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_');
}
```

This can be converted over to C#/.NET in a straightforward manner, however....

<sub>**IMPORTANT NOTE**: Do not use `String` to represent a JS script file that you'll be hashing *and* serving: the hash of a String is often different than the original file due to meta information-loss during decoding and re-encoding, even if the script's textual content is identical. For example, non-normalized Unicode bytes being normalized when decoded, missing the leading byte-order-mark (which `Encoding.UTF8` renders by default, btw!) or even line-break conversions from `\n` to `\r\n` (or vice-versa) depending on how your environment is set-up.</sub>

...for that reason, the code below uses `ReadOnlySpan<Byte>` to represent the JS script, **not `System.String`**.

---

The equivalent in .NET Core and .NET 5+ is this:

```
public static async Task<String> CalculateHashForGoogleAmpAsync( FileInfo jsFile )
{
    // DO NOT read the JS file into a String (and then re-encode it to Byte[] to get the hash)! Doing so will apply a potentially lossy Unicode transformation such that the resultant re-encoded bytes will be different to the source file bytes and so cause the hash to not match the source file.
    // Instead just read the file's raw bytes and hash that (it's much simpler too!)

    Byte[] bytes = await File.ReadAllBytesAsync( jsFile.FullName ).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return CalculateHashForGoogleAmp( js: bytes );
}

public static String CalculateHashForGoogleAmp( ReadOnlySpan<Byte> js )
{
    Byte[] hash          = SHA384.HashData( js );
    String hashBase64    = Convert.ToBase64String( hash );
    String hashBase64Url = hashBase64.TrimEnd('=').Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_'); // Or use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode`
    return "sha384-" + hashBase64Url;
}
```

In .NET Framework 4.x and .NET Standard 2.0 the `ReadAllBytesAsync` and `static Byte[] HashData()` methods are unavailable, but it's straightforward to workaround by reimplementing those methods... which is beyond the scope of this question, so here's a non-async version:

```
public static String CalculateHashForGoogleAmp( FileInfo jsFile )
{
    Byte[] sha384Hash;

    using( SHA384 algo = SHA384.Create() )
    using( FileStream fs = File.OpenRead( jsFile.FullName ) )
    {
       sha384Hash = algo.ComputeHash( fs );
    }
    
    return FormatHashForGoogleAmp( sha384Hash );
}

private static String FormatHashForGoogleAmp( Byte[] sha384 )
{
    String hashBase64    = Convert.ToBase64String( sha384 );
    String hashBase64Url = hashBase64.TrimEnd('=').Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_'); // Or use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode`
    return "sha384-" + hashBase64Url;
}
```

Comment: I should have mentioned I am using .NET Framework 4.7.2 so the SHA384.HashData method is not available to me. I can only use the ComputeHash function, but would you recommend passing the script in as a byte[] or a Stream?

Comment: @SamK I've updated my answer with .NET Framework 4.x compatible code. But why are you still using 4.7.2? There is no reason to not use 4.8 today.